# Update a value with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to update the `Selected`property of an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for a MVC-Combobox website using linq. However this is not working, as shown in the debbuging result: The `Count()` for the criteria returns an item, however the `Count()`for `.Selected == true`returns 0.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }

public CategoryModel Category
{
    get { return category; }
    set 
    {
        category = value;
        Categories.Where(x => x.Value == value.Id.ToString()).First().Selected = true;
    }

//Debugging Results
//?Categories.Where(x => x.Value == value.Id.ToString()).Count()
//1
//?Categories.Count(x => x.Selected == true);
//0

}
```

Update:
I guess the problem is more bound to the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, because the after changing Categories to an `ObservableCollection` it works fine (example below), even though Lin**Q** is not designed for changing data....

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(Categories.Where(x => x.Id == value.Id).FirstOrDefault().Description);

Categories.Where(x => x.Id == value.Id).FirstOrDefault().Description = "Stackoverflow";

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(Categories.Where(x => x.Id == value.Id).FirstOrDefault().Description);
```

Comment: "is not working" is not a sufficient error description. Any exceptions, error messages, unexepcted behaviour? BTW: LINQ stands for "language integrated **query** language", it's for _querying_, not for side effects and changing things.

Comment: BTW, your current approach will select one, but if there was already another selected that won't be deselected

Comment: besides the flaw pointed out by @TimSchmelter there must be something else wrong in code that is not shown here, because  if the value of Category is set,  the selected value must be updated on the item found, otherwise an exception would have been thrown. are you 100% sure the set on Category property  is reached in your code execution ?

Comment: For anybody downvoting this question. i think its inappropriate! the problem that the OP is facing is clear if you go through the code.  no need to downvote it. If he is misunderstanding a concept like LINQ help him! do not downvote it. hes not asking you to do his homework! its an actual problem that non so far was able to actually solve.

Comment: Where you have set the debugger brakpoints? `First().Selected` would throw an exception as Gerrie already mentioned if there was no item with that ID. So that property must have been set to true on one item. Where do you check `Categories.Count(x => x.Selected == true)`?

Comment: Where do you assign the items to the property `Categories`?

Comment: As shown in the edit, the problem lies somewhere in the way I populate the `DropDownList` in View or Controller. I'll search for that on my own. However, I would like to keep this question as an example for the "Downvoting people looking for help site" this has become. Btw: Thank you @GerriePretorius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEnumerable does not guarantee that changes get persisted across enumerations.
It all depends on the underlying implementation in the end (List, Array, Observable, etc).

Among the options that you have is to change your actual Categories to a writable collection (like List)...
But you might not be able to do that, or you might simply prefer to stay lean and keep using the IEnumerable.
In that case you could simply mutate the original collection and project it over the original

```
void Main()
{
    Categories = Load();

    var active = new Func<CategoryModel, int, CategoryModel>((category, match) =>
    {
        return new CategoryModel
        {
            Id = category.Id,
            Name = category.Name,
            Active = category.Id == match
        };
    });

    Categories = Categories.Select(p => active(p, 2));
    Categories.Dump();
}

public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> Load()
{
    yield return new CategoryModel { Id=1, Name = "one" };
    yield return new CategoryModel { Id=2, Name = "two" };
    yield return new CategoryModel { Id=3, Name = "three" };
}

public class CategoryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}


Id|Name|Active
1 one False 
2 two True 
3 three False
```

this is also to emphasize that you can use linq for "transformations" using "projections"

Comment: Sure, you can, you just shouldn't

Comment: Generally speaking you're right, as a purist (pun intended) one could follow the no surprises no side effects mantra and return new state to change state. To stay on the safe side, i'll reflect that in my answer as well

Comment: Nevertheless "Linq is not only about retrieving data, it is also a powerful tool for transforming data" or at least that's what the docs say :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/data-transformations-with-linq

Comment: you have misunderstood that sentence. If you'd read carefully you'd notice that they talk about creating a new type or different output. It's not about modifying the source silently while selecting something else.

Comment: check my update for the answer and you'll see that we should be on the same line

Answer (score 4):

LIN**Q** is to query your data-source not to modify it.

Your current approach has a drawback anyway, you would select one but you would not deselect the others. So you need a loop:

```
public CategoryModel Category
{
    get { return category; }
    set 
    {
        category = value;
        // consider to use a lock here to avoid multi threading issues
        foreach(SelectListItem catItem in Categories)
           catItem.Selected = catItem.Value == value.Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

I would use a method `SetSelectedCategory` instead of a property if i'd modify a collection.